# Excel text function in C

Tags: c, excel

One of the functionality of the text function in Excel is to convert any floating value below 1 into the HH:mm format. 
So if I do TEXT(0.756635, "HH:MM"), it will give me 18:09.
I want to know how this works. The thing is, I am changing my code to C, so I need a similar function in C that would change the float into that format.
Is there any library that could help me? Or does anyone know how the TEXT function in excel works?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = 0.756635;
    double h, m;

    x = x * 24;
    m = modf(x, &h) * 60;
    printf("%02d:%02d\n", (int)h, (int)m);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
18:09
```

If you want to avoid `math.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = 0.756635;
    double h, m;

    x = x * 24;
    h = (int)x;
    m = (x - h) * 60;
    printf("%02d:%02d\n", (int)h, (int)m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically whole day (24 hours) is equal to 1.

every hours is equal to  1/24          = 0.0416666667

every minute is equal to 1/(24*60)     = 0.0006944444

every second is equal to 1/(24*60*60)  = 0.0000115741

```
For E.g  0.756635 
HH: Integer Part of 0.756635*24=18
MM: Integer Part of MOD(0.756635*24,1)*60=09
```

Complete Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1*24-MOD(A1*24,1)&":"&MOD(A1*24,1)*60-MOD(MOD(A1*24,1)*60,1)&":"&ROUND(MOD(MOD(A1*24,1)*60,1)*60,0))
```

if you want 3:05:10 you need to do 3/24+5/(24*60)+10/(24*60*60) and you will get the number

if you are ok to count it to seconds you can use this formula (from time to number)

```
=HOUR(H27)/24+MINUTE(H27)/(24*60)+SECOND(H27)/(24*60*60)
```

I hope this helps, you can adapt the formulas to calculate it in any code that supports modulo

Answer (score 0):

It is basically Days in decimal format. So if suppose you have 0.25 value, you multiply it by 24 to get the hours. And if there is a decimal in the number of hours, multiply the right side of decimal by 60, to get the minutes. and if there is a decimal in minutes, multiply the right side of decimal by 60 to get the seconds.